# Phil sturgeon codeigniter template problem

Tags: php, templates, codeigniter

I have downloaded `phil sturgeon` codeigniter template system, but i keep getting this error:

```
Unable to load the requested file: default.php
```

you can see my project at github.com [at github](https://github.com/SimonJ/RapProject)

I just don't know what I'm doing wrong, I hope some one can help me out so I can start on my project :)

Best regards, Simon

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/SimonJ/RapProject/tree/master/application/themes

Try by renaming your theme folder to just "default" as stated in the config file:

https://github.com/SimonJ/RapProject/blob/master/application/config/template.php

```
$config['theme'] = 'default';
```